# git init fatal: bad config line 1 in file C:/Users/mypc/OneDrive/Documents/api/.git/config

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I'm trying to start a "git init" in my cmd and I'm returned with the error

```
git init fatal: bad config line 1 in file C:/Users/mypc/OneDrive/Documents/api/.git/config
```

I had started a git init before and for some reason I was not able to push to my branch, but my PC ended up restarting and now I can't do a "git init"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fatal%3A+bad+config+line+1+in+file

Comment: Can you tell me how I can access the .git/config folder?

Comment: Don't store your Git repositories in OneDrive or other cloud syncing services.  That's a great way to get corruption.

Comment: One of the main solutions is for me to enter the supposed .git/config folder and clean it inside, but the problem is that I don't know how to access this folder

Comment: The `.git` folder is a folder like any other folder, so you enter it the same way you enter any other folder. (However, OneDrive is *not* a folder like any other folder, so it may be the source of all kinds of problems.)